How can I make shiny fish scales like these in blender?
I want to make a mermaid character whose scales are iridescent and very reflective/shiny, but without the ugly and unwanted reflection of nearby objects, just like real fish scales. I tried to do it by lowering the roughness value, and although that made the scales a lot shinier, it also caused a lot of ugly dark reflections that real fish scales lack.
Here are a few pictures of what I want:




Here is what I could achieve at a roughness value of 4:


It's not horrible, but not nearly as shiny as real fish scales. What could I do to achieve that look above?
